# How to link the text field with my email in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I send the information that the user inset in text field `UITextField` to my email?
and how can I let the information page shows once, only at the first time the user enters the app?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is vague, but to take the data entered into a textfield and put it in a string just use:

```
NSString *theEmailBody = theTextField.text;
```

From there you can send an email using the standard Apple email framework:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail =[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *theEmailbody = theTextField.text;;
[mail setMessageBody:theEmailbody isHTML:NO];
```

or by making your own mail server and sending the HTTP request there.

Comment: You can run it and have your app send an email to yourself, and then view it when it arrives in your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in you function to send email.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail =[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailbody = textField.text;;
[mail setMessageBody:emailbody isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has sample code to show you how to set up in app email (linked below)

After you've done this, you can easily change (for example) the body of your email to be the contents of your textField by adding this where appropriate.

```
NSString *emailBody = myTextField.text;
```

Then additionally, if you wish for the information page to only be visible the first time the app is launched, look into `NSUserDefaults`. This will allow you to store and retrieve a value to let the app know wether or not to load your information page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865